# How can I remove all commits in git?

Tags: git, repository, git-commit

I have I repository in git and I made a lot of tests to learn it. Now I am on a level to start working. But I have all these test commits, that are disturbing me. Can I remove all commits to start clean? But it means I do not want to remove the changes. The code should stay the way it is now. I just want to have an empty git log.

Comment: As i know it is not possible to delete commits from git

Comment: do you want to make single commits all the changes? or you want to see all the files as a modified in git status but have no commits.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete .git directory from project root and reinitialize project

```
git init
```